# Android Emulator change system sound

Tags: audio, windows, android-emulator

So whenever I turn on emulator, system sound changes. It feels like lower frequencies are cut off, or some strange filter is turning on.

Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 4):

I'm running Windows 10 and I found that when launching the Android emulator, it would disable my Dolby audio enhancements. I simply had to turn it back on in the Sound properties.

[image]